# Is it possible to delete/create a constraint

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

[image: screenshot of constraints]

**I want to learn if there's a way to delete AND create a constraint**

So I have greenTop constrained to viewTop, purpleTop to greenBottom etc...

I want to be able to delete `greenTop-viewTop` constraint, delete `purpleTop-greenBottom`...and create a new `purpleTop-viewTop` constraint and a `greenTop-blackBottom`. (programmatically)

Effectively moving green to bottom and all others shift up one space.

**Note: I know i could just make each constrained to topView and adjust, but I'd like to learn this way.**

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use a UITableView?

Comment: this was an exercise for myself to learn deleting and addition of constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. You can make an IBOutlet to a constraint just like any other object. Call `removeConstraint` on the owner of that constraint to remove it,

```
someView.removeConstraint(someConstraint) // someConstraint is an IBOutlet
```

You cannot change the items or a relationship in a constraint, so #2 will not work.

Comment: @Dustin, what do you mean? How to create a constraint in code? Look at the methods in the NSLayoutConstraint class reference.

Comment: ok so I could create all possible constraints and activate/deactivate as need. But I can't understand the `constraintsWithVisualFormat` in reference, so I guess i could also use the `init(item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:)` reference

Comment: @Dustin, if you don't understand it,  read the document, "Auto Layout Concepts", and watch the videos on auto layout from the 2012 WWDC.